# How to fix a path with regex in php for PATHS and not break URLs?

Tags: php, regex, url

I want to replace `//` but not `://`. I'm using this function to fix broken urls:

```
function fix ($path)
{
    return preg_replace( "/\/+/", "/", $path );
}
```

For example:

Input:

```
a//a//s/b/d//df//a/s/
```

Output (collapsed blocks of more than one slash):

```
a/a/s/b/d/df/a/s/
```

That is OK, but if I pass a URL I break the `http://` part, and end up with `http:/`. For example:

```
http://www.domain.com/a/a/s/b/d/df/a/s/
```

I get:

```
http:/www.domain.com/a/a/s/b/d/df/a/s/
```

I want to keep the `http://` intact:

```
http://www.domain.com/a/a/s/b/d/df/a/s/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve it rather easily using a [negative lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html#lookbehind):

```
function fix ($path)
{
    return preg_replace("#(?<!:)/{2,}#", "/", $path);
}
```

Note that I've also changed your delimiter from `/` to `#`, so you don't have to escape slashes.
Working example: http://ideone.com/6zGBg

This can still match the second slash if you have more than two (`file:////` -> `file://`). If this is a problem, you can use `#(?<![:/])/{2,}#`.
Example: http://ideone.com/T2mlR

Answer (score 0):

```
return preg_replace("/[^:]\/+/", "/", $path);
```

Comment: This will remove a character for every block - `12///3` -> `1/3`